# Creating a Calendar in Tableau

Tags: sql-server, calendar, tableau-api

So I have a SQL data table that is nothing but a calendar for the next 200 years.  I join this to meaningful 'task data' by the date field on the calendar table matching the task completion date of the task table.  I am using that to build a calendar in Tableau and it looks great... at first:

[image]

That image above contains no filtering on the owner and shows all the days, even when the task count is 0.

But when I filter for an individual who has no tasks to count, the days disappear that are null:

[image]

If I hover over the white square, nothing is displayed in the detail drop down and notice that I've lost some days...  I went from 8/5 to 8/9.

I understand why this is happening (because the data simply doesn't exist in the filtered view), but there has got to be a way to still allow the day to display, but simply show a 0 for the task count instead of a null.  I've made a custom query and used isnull on both the task_Id and the Task_Owner but I still get the same view.  Other than creating dummy data in the db as a placeholder (which I am against) I am not sure how to achieve this.

I'm hoping someone out there has struggled and succeeded with this before and can help me out.  I feel like the zn(lookup) function in Tableau may be helpful but I can't seem to apply it in a way that accomplishes my goal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way to do this is to change your dataset to include all days for all users regardless of if they have a task or not. The reason is that `NULL` is non-existent, so no number of calculations `ISNULL`, etc are going to be evaluated for that particular "date". The reason you see it, is because Tableau presents it (in this case a blank square) but there is still no data behind it.

Comment: To add one more bit of clarity. When you are using `ISNULL`, `LOOKUP`, etc - you are effectively trying to create a new record of data, which Tableau cannot do.

Comment: I am in agreement of everything you said.  I am just going to have bite the bullet so to speak, and create a line item for each day for each user.  Thank you for taking a look and replying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
 ifnull([Task Count],0)
```

This would change any nulls to zeros.

Or save typing 6 whole characters and use

```
ZN([Task Count])
```

for the same effect

Comment: I have tried both, and neither work.  I think it's because there are not 'nulls' in the data for these days when viewing the entire data set.  It's only when filtered that this happens, and why what Nicarus suggested is the only thing that I know of that will actually work, unless there is a way to incorporate the filter into the zn function.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck.

For **most** datatypes, Tableau discovers the values for the dimensions from the query results. So in general, it won't know to leave a column for an absent value. But for dates, it knows about the possible values so can behave a little nicer.

That is, it can know that there should be a column for Sunday even though there were no data rows with that value.

So for your WEEKDAY(Date) field on the column shelf, right click and choose "Show missing values". You should see your missing columns. The same trick works for histogram bins as well. You should almost always check that option for histograms.

This can pad out your rows and columns to complete the range, but doesn't get your day of month showing. You can fix that using index() if you set the table calc partitioning correctly.

Comment: It sounded good, and I got excited, but it didn't display any missing columns :(

Comment: Actually I found out that this only works when not blending data, which I am; but also even then the index() function cannot return the index of a value that is not in existence.  Even when I removed the blending, and brought back in the columns, nothing else I did afterwards would display anything in the null cells.